# why it only shows the latest data from the json array

Tags: android, arrays, json

These are my `JSON` data:

```
[
    {"haberBaslik":"ekrem kimdir?"},
    {"haberBaslik":"doğa kimdir?"},
    {"haberBaslik":"biz kimiz?"},
    {"haberBaslik":"fatih naptı?"}
]
```

and this code only shows the latest data, but I need to show my all data

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(s);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String Haberbaslik = jsonobject.getString("haberBaslik");
    tv1.setText(Haberbaslik);
}
```

Comment: It shows the latest data, because you overwrite tv1 each time until the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(s);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
  String Haberbaslik = jsonobject.getString("haberBaslik");
  tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+ " "+Haberbaslik);
 }
```

Comment: This is more right, will print all the values with no space in between

Comment: @Carnal added spacing

Comment: Or alternate you can use `tv1.append()` instead of  `tv1.setText()`

Comment: Consider using `StringBuilder` when joining strings, it's far more efficient.